# Aggregate a matrix based on a lookup table in R

Tags: r, matrix, aggregation, lookup-tables

I tried to aggregate a large matrix (.csv) using information stored in another lookup table (.csv) in R.

```r
An example of the large matrix:
   z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8
z1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
z2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
z3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
z4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
z5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
z6  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
z7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
z8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have a lookup table tells me which zones to be aggregated together, an example:

```
old  new
z1   D1
z2   D1
z3   D1
z4   D4
z5   D4
z6   D6
z7   D7
z8   D7
```

This means I need to aggregate z1, z2, z3 into a group. z4 and z5 into another group, so on...

Based on this lookup table, I will create a new matrix looks like this:

```r
    D1  D4  D6  D7
D1  18  12   6  12
D4   3   2   1   2
D6   6   4   2   4
D7   3   2   1   2
```

This was done by summing the elements in the original matrix by the blocks shown below according to the lookup table:

```r
     z1 z2 z3   z4 z5   z6   z7 z8

z1   1  1  1    1  1    1    1  1
z2   2  2  2    2  2    2    2  2
z3   3  3  3    3  3    3    3  3

z4   0  0  0    0  0    0    0  0
z5   1  1  1    1  1    1    1  1

z6   2  2  2    2  2    2    2  2

z7   1  1  1    1  1    1    1  1
z8   0  0  0    0  0    0    0  0
```

I would love to know how to do this efficiently in R. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thank Martine Gal for editing. Thank you for your comment, akrun. To solve the problem, one way I can think of is adding the lookup column "new" to the original matrix, then group the rows according to this added column. Then, then group the columns in the similar way.  But want to know if there is smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `outer`

```
un1 <- unique(df1$new)    
out <- outer(un1, un1, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y)  
         sum(m1[df1$old[df1$new == x], df1$old[df1$new == y]])))
dimnames(out) <- list(un1, un1)
out
#   D1 D4 D6 D7
#D1 18 12  6 12
#D4  3  2  1  2
#D6  6  4  2  4
#D7  3  2  1  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(old = c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5", "z6", "z7", 
"z8"), new = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D4", "D4", "D6", "D7", "D7"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

m1 <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(8L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("z1", "z2", 
"z3", "z4", "z5", "z6", "z7", "z8"), c("z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", 
"z5", "z6", "z7", "z8")))
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your speedy solution. Really appreciated.

Comment: My R skills are not advanced enough to fully understand the code but I was able to apply your solution to my data. I found some problems with the results. Will the code work if the lookup table is something like this? Old: z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, New: D1, D2, D1, D4, D5, D1, D2, D4. That is the new ID is corresponding to non-continuous groups of old IDs?

Comment: @njwork It. should. have. worked. because. we. are. looping on the. unique values and then doing the `==`.  Here,, I. assumed the columns. are `character` class.  for old, new

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. However, after several rounds of checking, the results still seem not right. It seems that whenever the New ID is corresponding to one set of continuous Old IDs, the results are correct. If the New ID is corresponding to several noncontinuous groups of Old IDs, the results are not correct. In my example, Old and New IDs are characters, but in my real data, they are numbers (not sure if this matters).

Comment: @njwork If you can show an example using `dput` that doesn't work, it would be great.   I was using your example and it worked for me.   Anyway, if it was a generalized example in the post, all this could have been avoided.

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake when I was doing my checking. Your code works perfectly and the results are absolutely correct. Again, really sorry for my mistake. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @njwork It's okay .it can happen to anybody.  I was also surprised that it didn't work.  But, then I thought, it could be related to some missing values (NA)